# Register as a freelancer in Denmark

Tags: freelance, denmark

What should one do to register as a freelancer in Denmark, and how long the process takes?

- The person has an opholdstilladelse that allows to work and to change the job
- The person will be working for the companies outside Denmark, but in EU.
- The person is not EU citizen.

I'm interested in the whole process of what should one do. Would be really thankful for a detailed response.